# Repeating loop and adding columns in R

Tags: r, loops, repeat, calculated-columns

I am trying to build an R code that will take my loop and run it 20 times. Each time I would like to add a column to the existing data frame. Here I tried it by adding the code 3 times, but I feel like there must be an easier way to automate this. I am very grateful for any help.

My original data file (called "igel") contains two columns ("Year" and "Grid") and 1096 rows. With the loop I pick a random number from the column "Grid" and check whether it has been picked before. If so it adds 0 to a new column if not it adds 1.

Here the code:

```
a <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 2, nrow = 0))
x <- c("number", "count")
colnames(a) <- x

for (i in 1:1096) {
num_i <- sample(igel$Grid, 1)
count_i <- c(if (num_i %in% a$number == TRUE) {0} else {1})
a<-a %>% add_row(number = num_i, count = count_i)
}

b <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 2, nrow = 0))
x <- c("number", "count")
colnames(b) <- x

for (i in 1:1096) {
num_i <- sample(igel$Grid, 1)
count_i <- c(if (num_i %in% b$number == TRUE) {0} else {1})
b<-b %>% add_row(number = num_i, count = count_i)
}

c <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 2, nrow = 0))
x <- c("number", "count")
colnames(c) <- x

for (i in 1:1096) {
num_i <- sample(igel$Grid, 1)
count_i <- c(if (num_i %in% c$number == TRUE) {0} else {1})
c<-c %>% add_row(number = num_i, count = count_i)
}

df.total<- cbind(a$count,b$count, c$count)
```

Comment: @Parfait, how could I add up the numbers in the rows instead of printing them as 1 or 0? Can that be easily implemented in the code?

Comment: Please ask below my actual answer and not here below your question. Also, do you want to sum up the columns for one row as the result? If so, look into `colSums`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider `sapply` and even its wrapper, `replicate` and calculate *number* and *count* separately in vector calculations instead of growing object in loop by row.

```
# RUNS 3 SAMPLES OF igel$Grid 1,096 TIMES (ADJUST 3 TO ANY POSITIVE INT LIKE 20)
grid_number <- data.frame(replicate(3, replicate(1096, sample(igel$Grid, 1))))

# RUNS ACROSS 3 COLUMNS TO CHECK CURRENT ROW VALUE IS INCLUDED FOR ALL VALUES BEFORE ROW
grid_count <- sapply(grid_number, function(col)
                       sapply(seq_along(col), function(i) 
                                 ifelse(col[i] %in% col[1:(i-1)], 0, 1)
                             )
                     )
```

While above does not exactly reproduce your output, `df.total` (a matrix and not data frame), due to the random sampling within iterations, the two maintain similar structure:

```
dim(df.total)
# [1] 1096    3

dim(grid_count)
# [1] 1096    3
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the code! This works perfectly. However, I feel like even if I add "replace=FALSE" to the sample function, it still resamples the data points. I would expect to get different sequences with the same numbers (some occur multiple times, which is ok if they did in the starting sample). grid_number <- data.frame(replicate(2, replicate(1096, sample(igel_new$Grid, 1, replace=FALSE))))

Comment: In each iteration you only sample 1 number. Using `replace=FALSE` would differs from `TRUE` if your sample size is greater than number of input values.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I manage to solve it by using the following code: `grid_number <- data.frame(replicate(100, sample(igel_new$Grid,1096,replace=FALSE)))`

Answer (score 1):

Try to avoid iterating through rows. It is rarely necessary, if ever. Here is one approach (replace n with 1096 and elem with igel$Grid):

```
n = 20
elem = 1:5
df.total = list()
for  (i in 1:5) {
    a = data.frame(number = sample(elem, n, replace=TRUE))
    a$count = as.numeric(duplicated(a$number))
    df.total[[i]] = a
}

df.total = as.data.frame(df.total)
df.total
##    number count number.1 count.1 number.2 count.2 number.3 count.3 number.4 count.4
## 1       4     0        2       0        5       0        4       0        1       0
## 2       3     0        5       0        3       0        4       1        3       0
## 3       5     0        3       0        4       0        2       0        4       0
## 4       5     1        1       0        2       0        5       0        3       1
## 5       2     0        4       0        2       1        5       1        5       0
## 6       4     1        2       1        2       1        5       1        5       1
## 7       5     1        1       1        3       1        2       1        4       1
## 8       5     1        2       1        5       1        5       1        4       1
## 9       2     1        1       1        1       0        1       0        1       1
## 10      3     1        1       1        5       1        4       1        1       1
## 11      5     1        3       1        1       1        3       0        5       1
## 12      2     1        1       1        2       1        5       1        1       1
## 13      3     1        5       1        4       1        5       1        4       1
## 14      1     0        4       1        2       1        4       1        1       1
## 15      4     1        4       1        2       1        5       1        1       1
## 16      4     1        2       1        5       1        2       1        5       1
## 17      3     1        1       1        1       1        3       1        2       0
## 18      2     1        2       1        2       1        2       1        2       1
## 19      2     1        3       1        1       1        2       1        1       1
## 20      1     1        3       1        2       1        1       1        3       1
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the code. I tried both and both worked very well!